# Sharp edge in the middle of a flat surface with bevel modifier

Tags: shaders, normals, bevel

I'm trying to use a bevel modifier on my mesh, and for some reason a few spots are showing these weird sharp lines in the middle of flat surfaces, where no angle exists. I've attached a bunch of screencaps showing the issues, and demonstrating it doesn't seem to be an issue with the normals. If my bevel settings look a little weird, I have a problem where a lot of my meshes just refuse to show a bevel on anything but the "absolute" setting. Like otherwise all the edges stay sharp. If anyone can help me figure out why this one edge loop is sticking out in this one spot, I'd really appreciate it!

[image: the area in question]
[image: the topology]
[image: with face normals]
[image: with face orientation]
[image: with vertex normals]
[image: with split normals]
[image: another angle of the area with a matcap and split normals]
[[image: just the area at that angle8]
[image: another area with a similar issue]
[image: and same with split normals]

Comment: have you tried to remove doubled vertices or overlapping faces?

Comment: If you select those two co-planar faces and scale to zero in normal direction, does it help?